# K-fold cross-validation in keras with single output for binary class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am working with a convolutional neural network that i am using to classify cats and dogs, that has just one output for two classes. I need to use k-fold cross validation to find which set or pets breeds gives the best validation accuracy. The closest answer to my problem is in this question: [K fold cross validation using keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214527/k-fold-cross-validation-using-keras), but it doesnt use the original network model apparently and doesn't work for groups of pets with different breeds.

Inside Group 1, 2 and 3, I have 2 folders called Pets and inside each Pets folder i have two folders that are my classes: Cats and Dogs:
For example:

```
Group 1/
       Pets 1/
          cats/
            breeds_1_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_1_cats002.jpeg
     
           dogs/
            breeds_1_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_1_dogs002.jpeg
      Pets 2/
          cats/
            breeds_2_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_2_cats002.jpeg
     
          dogs/
            breeds_2_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_2_dogs002.jpeg
Group 2/
      Pets 1/
          cats/
            breeds_3_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_3_cats002.jpeg
           
          dogs/
            breeds_3_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_3_dogs002.jpeg
      Pets 2/
          cats/
            breeds_4_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_4_cats002.jpeg
           
           dogs/
            breeds_4_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_4_dogs002.jpeg
Group 3/
       Pets 1/
          cats/
            breeds_5_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_5_cats002.jpeg
           
          dogs/
            breeds_5_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_5_dogs002.jpeg
      Pets 2/
          cats/
            breeds_6_cats001.jpeg
            breeds_6_cats002.jpeg
           
          dogs/
            breeds_6_dogs001.jpeg
            breeds_6_dogs002.jpeg
```

What i want to do is use kfold and have as indices my groups.

For example: use group 1 and group 2 as training, group 3 as validation.
Then, group 1 and 3 as training and group 2 as validation and at last use group 2 and group 3 as training and group 1 as validation.

I've separated a dummy [dataset](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ngoocq1ph7pr77e/Pet_Images.rar/file) to help explain, my goals.

My problem is that i dont know how to use k-fold for a given multiple groups within a nested folder that has binary classes, where im using data generators for training and testing with binary output.
I need to use k-fold for my convolutional neural network, without having to modify my data augmentation or destroying my layers, in order to find the best validation accuracy and save their weights, here's my neural network:

```
        from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
        from keras.models import Sequential
        from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
        from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
        from keras import backend as K
        import numpy as np
        from keras.preprocessing import image
    
    img_width, img_height = 128, 160
    
    
    train_data_dir = '../input/pets/pets train'
    validation_data_dir = '../input/pets/pets testing'
    nb_train_samples = 4850 
    nb_validation_Samples = 3000 
    epochs = 100
    batch_size = 16
    
    
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
       input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
    else:
       input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
    
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        zoom_range=0.2,
        rotation_range=40,
       horizontal_flip=True,
    )
    
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    
        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
           train_data_dir,
           target_size=(img_width, img_height),
           batch_size=batch_size,
           class_mode='binary')
    
        validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_data_dir,
            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode="binary")

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['mse','accuracy'])


model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = nb_validation_Samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('pets-weights.npy')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `ImageDataGenerator` because according to the documentation, [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) expects an array of shape `(n_samples, features)`.

What you can do it load your images in memory, and create a custom CV splitter. I have a folder like this:

```
group1/
    cats/
        breeds_5_cats001.jpeg
        breeds_5_cats002.jpeg
    dogs/
        breeds_4_dogs001.jpeg
        breeds_4_dogs002.jpeg
group2/
    cats/
        breeds_5_cats001.jpeg
        breeds_5_cats002.jpeg
    dogs/
        breeds_4_dogs001.jpeg
        breeds_4_dogs002.jpeg
group3/
    cats/
        breeds_5_cats001.jpeg
        breeds_5_cats002.jpeg
    dogs/
        breeds_4_dogs001.jpeg
        breeds_4_dogs002.jpeg
```

I started with globbing the filenames and grouping them. You will need to change the glob pattern a little since my directory structure is slightly different. All it needs to do is get ALL the pictures, no matter the order.

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import os
from glob2 import glob
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import accumulate
import cv2
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
os.chdir('c:/users/nicol/documents/datasets/catsanddogs')

filenames = glob('*/*/*.jpg')

groups = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(filenames), key=lambda x: x.split(os.sep)[0])]
lengths = [0] + list(accumulate(map(len, groups)))
groups = [i for s in groups for i in s]
```

```
['group1\\cats\\cat.4001.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4002.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4003.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4004.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4005.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4006.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4007.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4008.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4009.jpg',
 'group1\\cats\\cat.4010.jpg']
```

Then I loaded all the pictures in an array and made an array of 0 and 1 for the categories. You will need to customize this according to your directory structure.

```
images = list()

for image in filenames:
    array = cv2.imread(image)/255
    resized = cv2.resize(array, (32, 32))
    images.append(resized)

X = np.array(images).astype(np.float32)

y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x.split(os.sep)[1] == 'cats', groups))).astype(int)
```

Then I built a `KerasClassifier`:

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])
    return model


keras_clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, epochs=1, batch_size=16, verbose=0)
```

Then I made a custom CV splitter, as explained [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics):

```
def three_fold_cv():
    i = 1
    while i <= 3:
        min_length = lengths[i - 1]
        max_length = lengths[i]
        idx = np.arange(min_length, max_length, dtype=int)
        yield idx, idx
        i += 1
```

Then I instantiated the custom CV splitter and ran the training:

```
tfc = three_fold_cv()
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=keras_clf, scoring="accuracy", X=X, y=y, cv=tfc)

print(accuracies)
```

Output:

```
[0.648 0.666 0.73 ]
```

Full code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import os
from glob2 import glob
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import accumulate
import cv2
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
os.chdir('c:/users/nicol/documents/datasets/catsanddogs')

filenames = glob('*/*/*.jpg')

groups = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(filenames), key=lambda x: x.split(os.sep)[0])]
lengths = [0] + list(accumulate(map(len, groups)))
groups = [i for s in groups for i in s]


images = list()

for image in filenames:
    array = cv2.imread(image)/255
    resized = cv2.resize(array, (32, 32))
    images.append(resized)

X = np.array(images).astype(np.float32)

y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x.split(os.sep)[1] == 'cats', groups))).astype(int)


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])
    return model


keras_clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, epochs=1, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

def three_fold_cv():
    i = 1
    while i <= 3:
        min_length = lengths[i - 1]
        max_length = lengths[i]
        idx = np.arange(min_length, max_length, dtype=int)
        yield idx, idx
        i += 1

tfc = three_fold_cv()
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=keras_clf, scoring="accuracy", X=X, y=y, cv=tfc)

print(accuracies)
```

```
[0.648 0.666 0.73 ]
```

Here's a copy/pastable example with the MNIST dataset:

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from itertools import accumulate
import tensorflow as tf

# Here's your dataset.
(xtrain, ytrain), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# You have three groups, as you wanted. They are 20,000 each.
x_group1, y_group1 = xtrain[:20_000], ytrain[:20_000]
x_group2, y_group2 = xtrain[20_000:40_000:], ytrain[20_000:40_000:]
x_group3, y_group3 = xtrain[40_000:60_000], ytrain[40_000:60_000]

# You need the accumulated lengths of the datasets: [0, 20000, 40000, 60000]
lengths = [0] + list(accumulate(map(len, [y_group1, y_group2, y_group3])))

# Now you need all three in a single dataset.
X = np.concatenate([x_group1, x_group2, x_group3], axis=0)[..., np.newaxis]
y = np.concatenate([y_group1, y_group2, y_group3], axis=0)


# KerasClassifier needs a model building function.
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])
    return model


# Creating the KerasClassifier.
keras_clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, epochs=1, batch_size=16, verbose=0)


# Creating the custom Cross-validation splitter. Splits are based on `lengths`.
def three_fold_cv():
    i = 1
    while i <= 3:
        min_length = lengths[i - 1]
        max_length = lengths[i]
        idx = np.arange(min_length, max_length, dtype=int)
        yield idx, idx
        i += 1

accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=keras_clf, scoring="accuracy", X=X, y=y, cv=three_fold_cv())

print(accuracies)
```

Comment: I can also make you an example with a toy dataset if the folder thing is too confusing

Comment: If it wouldn't be to much of a hassle, i would appreciate.

Comment: So, should i put dogs and cats inside the same group before loading them into memory, and assign labels? Like: 'dataset/group_1/cat1.jpg, dog1.jpg' then assign to y_1 = [0, 1] for every group?

Comment: I'm confused on how should classes separation should be loaded for every group when assigning indices to the cv function

Comment: Yes, they don't need to be in the same group. All you need is 3 groups of filenames, all mixed.